# General type of scala Enumerations Value

Tags: scala, playframework

I have few scala enumerations in my projet like this one:

```
object Tag extends Enumeration {
  type Tag = Value
  val BugFix, NewFeature, NewContent = Value

  implicit val tagFormat = EnumUtils.enumFormat(Tag)
}
```

where tag format is of type play.api.libs.json.Format[Tag.Value]. It can parse enum from JSON and I am also using it to serialize to text which I save to DB. For that every enum also has this code:

```
def parse(s: String) = {
  tagFormat.reads(JsString(s)) match {
    case s: JsSuccess[Tag] => s.get
    case _ => throw new ParseException(s"String of: $s is not parsable into [${getClass.getName}}]", 0)
  }
}
```

I am trying to extract this code into utility function. My attempt is as follows:

```
def generalParse[A](format: Format[Enumeration.Value])(s: String) = {
  format.reads(JsString(s)) match {
    case s: JsSuccess[A] => s.get
    case _ => throw new ParseException(s"String of: $s is not parsable into [${getClass.getName}}]", 0)
  }
}
```

And then each enum only needs this code:

```
def parse(s: String) = generalParse[Tag](tagFormat)
```

The problem is I can not figure out how to type generalParse format argument. Enumeration.Value does not work. I have also tried using Any and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you use type projection `Enumeration#Value`.

```
scala> def f[A <: Enumeration] = Days.Mon match { case _: A#Value => }
f: [A <: Enumeration]=> Unit

scala> f[Days.type]

scala> f[Colors.type]
```

If you want a useful match, you need an outer value to compare:

```
scala> def f[A <: Enumeration](a: A) = (Days.Mon: Any) match { case _: a.Value => }
f: [A <: Enumeration](a: A)Unit

scala> f(Days)

scala> f(Colors)
scala.MatchError: Mon (of class scala.Enumeration$Val)
  at .f(<console>:11)
  ... 33 elided
```